# SMTP server that forwards all mail to certain email

Tags: smtp

I have a staging server for several projects that tend to be exact copy of production server (hardware and installed software)

projects may send emails to some real addresses, and I want to avoid this by setting up some SMTP server that will forward all mail to a single configured email address

So the goal is that any message that is sent from this server (by any software) will be forwarded to a one configured email address

Comment: Your questions seems to be cut off.

Answer (score 0):

`exim4` can do this if you configure it to send all outgoing email to a smarthost.  I'm sure others can as well.